# python graph-tool: Fastest way to add edges without duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-tool

What's the fastest/most performant way to add edges without duplicates to a digraph in Python's `graph-tool`?

The naive solution would be to call `g.edge(u, v)` before adding edges, but that seems like quite a performance hit, especially in scale-free networks. Does `g.edge(u, v)` do lookups in O(1) if `g.set_fast_edge_removal()` has been set? I imagine whatever additional data structure `graph-tool` allocates for that is something along the lines of an edge list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it is best to add all the edges, and then remove the parallel edges.

You can add edges as a list:

```
g = gt.Graph()
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 2)]
g.add_edge_list(edges)
gt.remove_parallel_edges(g)
```